# Can I change the template search behavior of class based views?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I have an app called transactions. Within this app I have a model called BatchFile.  In my views.py file, I subclass ListView (amongst others).  The default behavior is that django thinks batchfile_list.html should be located at:

```
templates/transactions/batchfile_list.html
```

That's great, but the folder is getting crowded.  I'm able to add "templates/transactions/batchfiles" to TEMPLATE_DIRS, but because the default behavior is to look for appname/modelname_type.html that requires that I put my templates in:

```
templates/transactions/batchfiles/transactions/batchfile_list.html
```

when I'd really like it to be in:

```
templates/transactions/batchfiles/batchfile_list.html
```

or my optimal result:

```
templates/transactions/batchfiles/list.html
```

Are there configuration options that would allow me to do this?  I know the optimal result is probably not cleanly achieved, but I was hoping for at least the slightly less optimal result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to specify `template_name`:

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    template_name = "transactions/batchfiles/list.html"
```

An alternative is to override `get_template_names`:

```
class MyListView(ListView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["transactions/batchfiles/list.html"]
```

Note that it needs to return a list of possible template locations.

In this case there would only be one which is the desired location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I wanted to avoid explicitly naming all the templates.  I am looking at the code for Multiple and [SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/) and it looks like the name creation doesn't accept any options/configurations.  I'm fairly new to Django and Python, is there any way for me to override get_templates in these 2 Mixins?

Comment: @user116510: you can but one view at a time. So you could create your own mixin and add that to all your class-based view. Alternatively you could go with Django's default. After all, the problem you're trying to solve is only a "full directory", not much else.

Comment: @simion-visser Ok, thanks.  I think you are right, I'll just stick with the default.